# Apollo Client v3 Delete cache entries after given time period

Tags: caching, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I am wondering if there is a way to expire cached items after a certain time period, e.g., 24 hours.

I know that Apollo Client v3 provides methods such as `cache.evict` and `cache.gc` which are a good start and I am already using; however, I want a way to delete cache items after a given time period.

What I am doing at the minute is adding a TimeToLive field to every object in my Apollo schema, and when the backend returns an object, the field is populated with the current time + 24 hours (i.e. the time in 24 hours time). Then when I query the data in the front end, I check the to see if the TimeToLive field of the returned data is in the future (if not that means the data was definitely retrieved from the cache and in which case I call the `refetch` function, which forces the query to fetch the data from the server. However, this doesn't seem like the best way to do things, mainly because I have to iterate over every result in the returned data anch check if any of the returned objects are expired; and if so, everything is refetched.

Another solution I thought of was to use something like [React Native Queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-queue) and have a background task that periodically checks the cache and deleted items that have expired. But again, I am not totally sold on this solution.

For a little bit of context here: I am building a cooking / recipes app - and recipes / posts are cached on the device; however, my concern is that a user could delete a post, but everyone else who has that post cached would still be able to see it, and hence by expiring the cached item at least they would only be able to see for a number of hours before it is removed. However they might be a better way to do this all together, i.e. have the sever contact clients with the cached item (though I couldn't think of any low lift solutions at the time of writing this)

Comment: Can't find a simple solution for this common need either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[apollo-invalidation-policies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-invalidation-policies) replaces the Apollo-client InMemoryCache with InvalidationPolicyCache and within the typePolicies you can specify a timeToLive field. If an object is accessed beyond their TTL, they are evicted and no data is returned.